# getting value from dropdown in php

Tags: php, html, web

How do I get the selected value from the dropdown and assign the form's action property to it?

Here is my code :

```
<form id="form" action"test.php" method="post">
    <select id="bok_name" name="bok_name">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value='.$row['bok_name'].'>'.$row['bok_name'].'</option>'; 
        } ?>
    </select>
</form>

<form action="<?php $filed = $_post['bok_name'];
    if($filed = 'new life') echo "http://www.google.com"?> method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="check" name="check"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You will need to use some javascript I think, assuming you want your selection to become the form action

Answer (score 0):

Why not in javascript?

```
$('#bok_name').change(function(){
    $('#form2').attr('action',$(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a typo in this line

```
if($filed = 'new life')
```

should be

```
if($filed == 'new life')
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to :

```
<form id="form" action"test.php" method="post">
    <select id="bok_name" name="bok_name">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value='.$row['bok_name'].'>'.$row['bok_name'].'</option>'; 
    } ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="check" name="check"/>
</form>
```

test.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['check']))
{
   $field = $_POST['bok_name'];
   if($field == 'new life')
   {
      header('lacation:www.google.com');
   }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not do what you are trying to do since php  does not work like javascript. Form needs to be submitted in order to pass the value to next form. You make two different forms and provide select options as you want in first and make user submit this form and take them to next form with that form value what you got last time. It will be bit of trouble for user so I will suggest second way.

Or use javascript to get first value onselect function and take it to next form and auto submit that :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all add a submit button to get the post values.
Use javascript to get the selected option. Assign a value to the selected option using php.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add submit button. that's why you are not able to send to value of `bok_name` to your `test.php`.

```
 <form id="form" action"test.php" method="post">
          <select id="bok_name" name="bok_name">
            <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value=' . $row['bok_name'] . '>' . $row['bok_name'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

and I am assuming that below form is on your `test.php` in which you need to compare value `$filed == 'new life'` right now you are assigning value by `$filed = 'new life'`.

```
<?php $filed = $_post['bok_name']; ?>
<form action="<?php if($filed == 'new life') echo "http://www.google.com"; ?> method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="check" name="check"/>
</form>
```